# Data reduction and xgboost(or other boosting and decisision tree methods)

Tags: cart, dimensionality-reduction, boosting

I wonder, does data reduction(ex:factor analysis) have an impact on the result of boosting(ex:xgboost) or decision trees methods other than time gain?

Comment: I use Boruta, and it helps me reduce the dimensionality of the data using the CART model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:

1. If you lose important elements of the data in the reduction, it can
   harm the fit.
2. If you lose noise-containing elements of the data in the reduction,
   it can improve the fit.

Factor Analysis appears to be a subset of principal component methods, in that it describes the data using a weighted subset of the eigenvectors.  This means that, in a very general sense, as long as the minimum eigenvalue elements are being removed, the second case tends to prevail.

Implications for boosting.  An individual CART has breaks that are perpendicular to the axes.  The boosted ensemble is made out of weighted sums of these aligned "boxes", but doesn't do linear combinations in the sense of non-perpendicular.  The factor analysis can make factors (columns) that are non-perpendicular, and then the learner can operate on those.  That has the opportunity to make things more accurate in with lower learner complexity.

Comment: (+1) I would add that a common mistake is to think that the dimensions with maximum variance (such as PC1 and PC2 in a PCA) are automatically those of interest, and to discount the subsequent dimensions. But there's no good reason to expect that this is true.

Comment: I suspect this is part of the foundation of V-optimal DOE, the one that you can weight with experimental costs and thus account for difficulty in execution when building the design, and I have wanted to explore that for a while.